# Linear Programming Production Process Constraint Relationship

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Objective function is to maximize profit.
Decision variables is how much qty of $C$ and $D$ to produce?

Raw material can produce either $A$ or $B$.

Product $C$ requires an input of qty $A$ and $\frac{1}{2}B$.
Product $D$ requires an input of qty $2A$ and $B$.
Cost to produce $A$ is $2$ and $B$ is $4$.

In the constraint, if I put $A + \frac{1}{2}B=C$, the program will set $B$ to 0 as its cost is higher.

How to write the constraint so that $C$ must consist exactly the qty ratio of $A$ and $\frac{1}{2}B$?

Comment: I suggest that you add a constraint of the form 2A-B=0, then you always have enough A and B to produce C and D.

Comment: I want to add that , for processes, it is crucial to have a constraint to link the output to the input such as Output <= Input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write $A+\frac{B}{2} = C$, it means that to produce $1$ unit of $C$ you can either use $1$ unit of $A$ or half a unit of $B$.

What you want is $1$ unit of $A$ AND half a unit of $B$, so you need to write the constraint the other way around :
\begin{align}
C &= A \\
C &= 2B
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you ! you're right !